# Regex for capturng all urls with a "/" at the end apart from "/cms/"

Tags: regex

I want to capture all urls with a "/" at the end apart from "/cms/"

I currently have this, but it's not right. *I'm really bad at regex*:

```
(.*[^\/cms\/])\/$
```

https://regex101.com/r/Bxa6Ma/1

If I do this:

```
(.*[^cms\/])\/$
```

It works except for when a url has /blahcms/ - at which point it should once again capture it, that's why i'm trying to also include a "/" at the beginning too.

**Example url I would like to catch:**

- example/hitherecms/
- example/bingbangboomcms/

**Example url I do not want to catch:**

- example/cms/
- example/cms
- example/bingbangboom

*This regex will be used inside a Web.config rewrite rule.*

Comment: What language is it? It's trivial to do with lookbehind, a bit more complicated with JS (that doesn't support lookbehind).

Comment: can you post some exemplary urls ?

Comment: Example URL's would make this a lot easier if you can supply some.

Comment: @JosephGarrone, @ RomanPerekhrest - Thanks guys, I have now done so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is buggy, as it doesn't match the string if either `s`, `m`, `c`, or backslash precedes the ending backslash. It's generally wrong to use character class in place of negative lookahead.

One possible approach to solve this in the language that doesn't support negative lookbehind (JavaScript is a prominent example):

```
^(?:(?!\/cms\/$).)*\/$
```

... or (seems to be far more performant):

```
(?:(?!\/cms).{4}|^.{0,3})\/$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fA2RO1/1).

It's trivial to do with negative lookbehind, though:

```
^.*(?<!\/cms)\/$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CJjeyE/1). Note that regex flavor's change. You can skip `^.*` part if you only need to test, not match.